# Highlight the first value of dropdown list

Tags: jquery

```
function load() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'abc.view',
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      $("#myList").empty();
      var myList = $("#myList");

      jQuery.each(objData, function(key, value) {
        myList.append($("<option />").val(key).text(value));

      });
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please mention what is your query. It is not clear what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#myList").val($("#myList option:first").val());
```